# C# Regex: only letters followed by an optional 

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.0

I am looking for a way to get words out of a sentence. I am pretty far with the following expression:

```
\b([a-zA-Z]+?)\b
```

but there are some occurrences that it counts a word when I want it not to. E.g a word followed by more than one period like "text..". So, in my regex I want to have the period to be at the end of a word zero or one time. Inserting `\.?` did not do the trick, and variations on this have not yielded anything fruitful either.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: @bdukes, why did you add a backslash when you edited?

Comment: bdukes was right, that was how I put it!

Comment: + I have another weird problem. In FF I can click all I want on Add Comment, but nothing is happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single dot means any character. You must escape it as

```
\.?
```

Maybe you want an expression like this:

```
\w+\.?
```

or

```
\p{L}+\.?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `\.?` (and not `.?`) because the period has special meaning in regexes.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid a match on your example "test.." you ask for you not only need to put the `\.?` for checking first character after the word to be a dot but also look one character further to check the second character after the word.

I did end up with something like this
`\w{2,}\.?[^.]`

You should also consider that a sentence not always ends with a `.` but also `!` or `?` and alike.

I usually use [rubulator.com](http://rubular.com/r/OVrJ5WwOKy) to quick test a regexp